# How field "Bound Import Directory" works?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

I am interested in the operation of the PE format.

I opened the Windows 7 (32-bit) calculator with CFF Explorer software.

When I open the "Data Directories" field, I discover that the "Bound Import Directory" field (index 11) has an RVA of 0x270 and a size of 0x154.

But when I open the "section headers" field, I discover that my first section (.text) starts in 0x1000 in Virtual Address.

I deduce that my field "Bound Import Directory RVA" does not point to virtual address, because my first section is mapped to 0x1000 and that 0x270 is lower.

Would it be a physical address (offset from the beginning of the file)?

I would also like to know if other entries of "Data Directories" can be in the same situation.

In addition, the entry "Bound Import Directory RVA" is highlighted in red by CFF Explorer, however I have not changed and the executable works very well.

Thanking you in advance for your answers,

Comment: To put it simply, yes the bound import 'RVA' is actually an **offset** in the file, not a real RVA (the content is usually located right after the section headers). The fact that is is highlighted is just because CFF is confused by the field value, thinking it's an RVA.

Comment: I thank you for your answer.
It confirms what I thought.
I would also need to know the list of fields among the 16 that are not "real RVA". From the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format
I deduce that the following fields are offsets in the file: Certificate Table, Architecture, Global Ptr, Load Config Table, Import Bound, IAT, Delay Import Descriptor.
Can you confirm that?

Comment: Bound imports are on the header page